# WP7 XNA without DX10

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

XNA game fails to deploy on the WP7 emulator, I suppose, it's because I have Intel GMA950 video adapter without DX10 support (it says that I have incompatible monitor adapter). Is it possible to use emulator & xna without changing PC configuration?

Comment: Error text: The current display adapter does not meet the emulator requirements to run XNA framework applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Project properties and see if you have the Reach profile selected or HiDef.  If you have HiDef, change it to Reach.  I have a laptop with an Intel G945 video adapter and HiDef doesnt work, but Reach does.

**EDIT**

I have just seen your edit and unfortunately you won't be able to do anything unless you change the the graphics device.

Comment: It's sad, because it's my netbook and I write a lot of code on it (in undeground, train, at work, etc...). Thanks!

Comment: Just a clarification: XNA projects for WP7 always use the Reach profile, due to the platform's limitations.